# replace text in between % with field from DB

Tags: php

I would like to replace text in between two `%` symbols.

For example :

`%name%` would be replaced with `$contact->name` (which is a field in the DB)

and for example if someone puts 'email' instead of name it will replace that with `$contact->email`

so what ever is between the `%`-symbol, it will add at the end of $contact->XXXX

I am getting the info from the db with the following code

```
$contact = $this->db->get_where("contacts", ["id" => "1"]);
$contact = $contact->row();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable for this.

```
class Foo{
    public $bar;
    public $fez;
}

$f = new Foo();
$property = "bar";
$f->{$property} = "hello!";

echo $f->bar; // hello!
```

Hope I understood your question correctly..